# jQuery FullCalendar change editable properties of particular TIME on a calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

How can I block a specific timeslot in a fullcalendar.js?

I need to block 1pm - 2pm so no one can add any task or event during that time, but the thing is that I also need them to be able to add their tasks up to 1pm which overlaps with lunchbreak (starttime).

```
function isOverlapLunchBreak(task_sdate, task_edate) {
    console.log(task_sdate);
    console.log(task_edate);
    var l_start = 13;
    var l_end = 14;
    var r = false
    if (task_sdate.getHours() >= l_start && task_sdate.getHours() > l_end && task_sdate.getHours() < l_end)
    {
        r = true;
        //alert('first');
    }

    if (task_edate.getHours() >= l_start && task_edate.getHours() >= l_end && task_sdate.getHours() < l_end)
    {
        r = true;
        //alert('second');
    }

    if (task_sdate.getHours() <= l_start && task_edate.getHours() <= l_end && task_edate.getHours() >= l_start)
    {
        r = true;
        //alert('third');
    }

    if (r) {
        GritterMessageDanger('DTR - Time In', 'You cannot add task during break hours.');
        return true;
    }
}
```

The above blocks 1pm to 2pm, but the users cannot drag their tasks up to 1pm. It only accepts up to 12:59pm. Is it possible to change the "var l_start = 13;" to "var l_start = 13:01;"?

How can I do this?

Sample:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use your code, you can manipulate dates using the built-in moment.js. Read their docs, it's super easy. E.g. you would use

```
var start_date = moment("13:00:01")
if (start_date.hours() ...
```

to create possibly what you need.

As an alternative to your code is probably using `eventConstraint`, `businessHours` and `eventDragStop` in fullCalendar.